# Как отписаться от события внутри делегата?

Tags: c#

Есть некоторый кусочек кода

```
var d = new MouseEventHandler((o, e) => 
{
    wnd.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
    wnd.DragMove();
});
wnd.PreviewMouseMove += d;
```

Требуется отписаться от события `PreviewMouseMove` внутри тела делегата. То есть событие должно сработать один раз. Как это сделать?

**UPD:**

Хотелось бы без создания именованной функции.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Чтобы переменная `d` была видна внутри замыкания - ее надо объявить до этого самого замыкания.

```
MouseEventHandler d = null;

d = new MouseEventHandler((o, e) => 
{
    wnd.PreviewMouseMove -= d;
    wnd.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
    wnd.DragMove();
});
wnd.PreviewMouseMove += d;
```